# After changing Base URL & Base Link URL in Magento 1.9.2 Admin (System > Configuration > Web > ebsite is stuck in redirect loop

Tags: magento-1.9

After changing `Base URL` & `Base Link URL` in `Magento 1.9.2` 
Admin

`System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure`,

website is stuck in redirect loop.

Comment: delete `var/cache` folder from magento root

Comment: i had done this but i cant even login to admin panel

Comment: you want to revert your url?

Comment: yes so taht i can login into admin panel.after change base url in syatem>confuguration  wesbsite 
www.papaak.com  get redirect to this http://papaak.co.in/

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Comment: if i do this Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 858431348986 this error

Comment: i just want login in admin panel

Comment: Check /tmp directory in your sever

Comment: are u using https so that you put the https URL at System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database

fire below Query

`SELECT * FROM mgnt_core_config_data WHERE path like '%base_url%'`

and change the url for this two `secure` and `unsecure_url`

also disable cache from db fire below code and change the value to `0`

`select * from core_cache_option;`

Comment: still same no effect

Comment: Delete `var/cache` folder that is the only issue

Comment: i delete sir but i cant login in admin pane

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: sir i changed it many times even that i cant login into admin panel

Comment: @user45108 `papaak.co.in ` working in my browser please clear your browser cache and cookies

Comment: please open www.papaak.com

Comment: clear all var below  files `downloader/.cache/',
        'downloader/pearlib/cache/*',
        'downloader/pearlib/download/*',
        'var/cache/',
        'var/locks/',
        'var/log/',
        'var/report/'
        'var/tmp/'`

Comment: please note `var/session` will remove all session and items in cart please be careful with that

Answer (score 0):

this is the issue of space. you enter space in Base URL & Base Link URL. remove space in that field. all work fine.

Comment: no space i had given in databsae for base url and link url

Comment: your site is live?

Comment: http://papaak.co.in/ yes but when i try to open www.papaak.com it get redirect to  http://papaak.co.in/

Comment: its problem in www.papaak.com s .htaccess file

Comment: can you explain whats your actual problem. because in question you write that After changing Base URL  website is stuck in redirect loop.

Comment: m problem is that i changed my url from system>configuration>web after that when my trying tom loin in admin panel i cant login

Comment: that domain is point to same directory ?

Comment: you create test.php file and just sipaly print message hello
after change url access this file. it will print msg or not ? just check

Comment: it prints hello http://papaak.co.in/test.php

Comment: now change the url that you want

Comment: where i can change url i really getting confused

Comment: you can change in directoly database
change in core_config_data table